# Problems appending lists to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using this code to append values into a python dictionary:

```
df = {}

def set_key(dictionary, key, value):
     if key not in dictionary:
         dictionary[key] = value
     elif type(dictionary[key]) == list:
         dictionary[key].append(value)
     else:
         dictionary[key] = [dictionary[key], value]

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
set_key(df, 'extra_contents', list1)
print(df)

output> {'extra_contents': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

The problem is that when I try to execute this function again the following happens:

```
list2 = ['d', 'e']
set_key(df, 'extra_contents', list2)
print(df)

output> {'extra_contents': ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']]}
```

Here's my desired output:

```
{'extra_contents': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]}
```

How can I turn the current output to the desired output? If possible only by changing the function I'm using.

My main goal here is to later turn this dict into a pandas dataframe, therefore, each list would be a row in "extra_contents" column.

Comment: Your desired output `{'extra_contents': ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']}` doesn't seem to be a valid expression. Did you mean `{'extra_contents': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]}` or `{'extra_contents': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}`?

Comment: The first one! ```{'extra_contents': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]} ```. Just edited the question to correct it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

```py
def set_key(dictionary, key, value):
      if key in dictionary:
          dictionary[key].append(value)
      else:
          dictionary[key]=[value]
```

Comment: that's great, but what if I had to append values to the dict that are not lists? Let's say I'll append to another key the following: `set_key(df, "new_key", 34)` wouldn't that code put the 34 inside a list?

Comment: Ok but there's still a problem, each time I insert a new list, it will add another list inside. So my output if I used the function for the list2 again would be `{'extra_contents': [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']], ['d', 'e']]}` instead of  `{'extra_contents': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['d', 'e']]}`

Comment: Actually your previous code worked better for me! `def set_key(dictionary, key, value):
     if key in dictionary:
         dictionary[key].append(value)
     
     else:
         dictionary[key]=[value]`.